# Have issues when installing virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper

Tags: macos, pip

Have issues when installing virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper, and get the below errors when I try. Can anyone help with these?

```
MacBook-Pro:~ adrian$ pip install virtualenvwrapper
Collecting virtualenvwrapper
  Using cached virtualenvwrapper-4.7.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/pbr/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'pbr' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for pbr
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/8y/01r_vzmn1bb30myt3sbb5j5m0000gn/T/pip-build-umhhmr_f/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        pbr=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 668, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pbr')
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/8y/01r_vzmn1bb30myt3sbb5j5m0000gn/T/pip-build-umhhmr_f/virtualenvwrapper/

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you as well :) Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Try to install pbr first:

```
pip install pbr
```

Comment: u know what,  most tutorials about pip install  does not mention what dependencies we have to install first.